# Android - Horizontally scrolling both left and right using RecyclerView

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, smoothing

I made a custom LayoutManager to smooth scroll after clicking a left or right button.  Everything works when scrolling left only!  For right, `computeScrollVectorForPosition` never event gets called. What gives?  I've tried setting `mReverseLayout` when going right, but that hasn't help. Anything I'm not doing/overlooking?

```
public class SmoothScrollLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

private static final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH =  50f;
private Context context;
public boolean shouldGoRight = false;

public SmoothScrollLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
    LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(context) {

        @Override
        public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
            if (getChildCount() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            final int firstChildPos = getPosition(getChildAt(0));
            final int direction = targetPosition < firstChildPos != shouldGoRight ? -1 : 1;
            return new PointF(direction, 0);

        }

        @Override
        protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
            return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
        }
    };

    smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
    startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`comupteScrollVectorForPosition` is only called to find out the direction into which the `LinearSmoothScroller` has to scroll to eventually find the element. If the LinearSmoothScroller already thinks to know where the element is, it will not call this function. This is the case for elements that are already loaded to be shown, like your elements to the right.